How many series does echart support for line graph
I have an array of user objects. Each user has an array of dates. For each date there is an "activity counter". I would like to output this information as a line graph using echart.js, where the x axis is the date, y is the activity bar, the line on the graph is the individual user.
I see big performance problems with more than 200 users on the graph. I don't understand if echart really can't render 200 lines well or if the problem is in my data?
I transfer data for each user as a separate series:
const options = {
  //
  //...some basic settings,
  series: [
    {
      "type": "line",
      "data": "0", "0", "7", ...other ~30 activity-points..., "3"
    },
    {
      "type": "line",
      "data": "15", "43", "17", ...other ~30 activity-points..., "6"
    },
    ...other ~200 data-objects
  ]
}
myChart.setOption(option);

I have now reproduced the example locally to encapsulate the environment, on a blank page, just a script with a graph, with minimal settings. And I get performance problems when trying to interact with a graph: mouseMove causes huge rendering lags. The more settings you make (for example, add a stack option to display a line graph), the worse it gets.

Large amounts of data will always impose performance cost. Here, here and here are some realted posts which might be helpful.
